# How does the manipulation of time allow contact with other dimensions?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, time

In the TNG episode *We'll always have Paris*, a time experiment allows a man to be partially in our dimensions and partially in other dimensions.  How does the manipulation of time allow contact with other dimensions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In-universe, the answer is that Manheim's theories are being [explained](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/124.htm) by a layperson (Jenice Manheim) who seems to have only the vaguest understanding of her husband's work. She isn't a scientist and was kept well away from his experiments and locked in a safe-room.

> **DATA:** *Do you know the nature of Doctor Manheim's work?*
>
> **JENICE:** *Paul's always been interested in time. He's never believed that it was immutable, any more than space is immutable. Over
>   the last decade, he came to believe that we reside in one of infinite
>   dimensions, and what holds us here is the constancy of time. Change
>   that and it would be what he called opening the window to those other
>   dimensions.*

In the [earlier versions](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/124.txt) of the script, Manheim's own explanation is barely more coherent and is subject to an airy hand-wave as being too complex for someone as smart as Picard to understand, let alone us mere mortals out in TV-Land.

> **PICARD :** *I'd rather hear it from you personally, a condensed version.*
>
> **MANHEIM :** *There is hardly a condensed version of the most complex theory of the twenty-fourth century, Captain Picard, but if you
>   insist, I'll attempt one that even you will be able to understand.*
>
> *A star four light years away went nova. I have been able to mathematically... "latch" onto the incredible gravity of this smooth
>   black globe and direct that energy, that nearly immeasurable force,
>   into space.*
>
> **PICARD :** *So -- this energy, directed into space, then what?*
>
> **MANHEIM :** *Then, abracadabra, Captain Picard, we all see God! A window to another dimension, isn't that how you put it? So
>   pedestrian.*